# Converting values in a list of dictionaries from string to float

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, where each item in each dictionary is a string. I am trying to build a formula to pass the whole dataset through and convert all values to a float.

Each dictionary has the following structure:

```
{'dropoff_datetime': '2014-11-26T22:31:00.000',
 'dropoff_latitude': '40.746769999999998',
 'dropoff_longitude': '-73.997450000000001',
 'fare_amount': '52',
 'imp_surcharge': '0',
 'mta_tax': '0.5',
 'passenger_count': '1',
 'payment_type': 'CSH',
 'pickup_datetime': '2014-11-26T21:59:00.000',
 'pickup_latitude': '40.64499',
 'pickup_longitude': '-73.781149999999997',
 'rate_code': '2',
 'tip_amount': '0',
 'tolls_amount': '5.3300000000000001',
 'total_amount': '57.829999999999998',
 'trip_distance': '18.379999999999999',
 'vendor_id': 'VTS'}
```

I am trying to cast the values into floats

```
def float_values(trips):    
    for trip in trips:
        for value in trip:
            trip[value] = float(trip[value])
```

I am getting error message string indices must be integers

Comment: `trip` is a string. I think you may want `trips[trip][value] = float(trips[trip][value])` it's hard to tell without a [mcve].

Comment: Is each `trip` an actual `dict` or is it a string representation of a `dict`?

Comment: You're iterating down too far.  The values are the individual letters of the dict value.  It's much cleaner to iterate through a dict using dict.items()

Comment: Each trip is a dictionary within a list of dictionaries 'trips'

Comment: I don't understand iterating down too far?

Comment: You probably need something like `for trip in trips: for value in trip.values(): ...`

Comment: I don't see how that would be a solution heike?

Comment: @CarterB no one can help you unless you show an example that begins with `trips = ...`. As I said before, `trip` is a string. As to *why* it's a string is a mystery without more information.

Comment: trips is a list of dictionaries, one of which I have posted above

Comment: There is no list in the code you've posted above.

Comment: I know. I have posted one dictionary, of a list of dictionaries so you can understand the structure of the data. trips is a list of dictionaries - I have posted one of these dictionaries above.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the dictionary using `items()` or `iteritems()` depending on your version of python. Some of the values in your dictionary are strings, and therefore, can't be converted. A naive solution is as follows:

```py
def float_values(trips):
    for key, value in trips.items():
        try:
            trips[key] = float(value)
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

You could also change this to use a comprehension if you so wish, but take care with the `isdigit()` function

```py
def float_values(trips):
    return {key: float(value) if value.isdigit() else value for key, value in trips.items()}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this answer, Some of the values in your dictionary are strings, and therefore, can't be converted - but it is exactly strings I am trying to convert

Comment: How can you convert 'VTS' to a float?

Comment: How would this change if all the values in the dict were definitely strings of digits

Comment: You can't convert 'VTS' to a float. The logic I have provided will convert all valid values to floats.

Answer (score 0):

Add the required code and insert some basic debugging.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

```
def float_values(trips):
    for trip in trips:
        print("trip =", trip)
        for value in trip:
            print("value =", value)
            trip[value] = float(trip[value])

data = {
    'dropoff_datetime': '2014-11-26T22:31:00.000',
    'dropoff_latitude': '40.746769999999998',
    'dropoff_longitude': '-73.997450000000001',
 }

float_values(data)
```

Output:

```
trip = dropoff_datetime
value = d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 14, in <module>
    float_values(data)
  File "so.py", line 6, in float_values
    trip[value] = float(trip[value])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

You extracted the dict key.  Then, instead of using that to index the dict, you decided to iterate through the individual characters of the key itself.  Finally, you tried to use the individual letter as an index into the key, which is a simple string.

That's what the Python interpreter saw; it threw you an error message.  Instead, delete that innermost loop.  `trips` is the dict, and you use the extracted key to index it:

```
trips[trip] = float ...
```